# Game of Thrones: When exactly to use the Valyrian Steel Blade when playing with Tides of Battle?

Tags: game-of-thrones

My question can **litteraly be found in the [errata/FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/agot-bg-2nd-ed/support/faq/VA65_AGoT2_FAQ_v1_4.pdf)**, but the given answer is still ambiguous.

Quoting the errata/FAQ:

> *Q: When exactly is the decision made to use the Valyrian Steel Blade’s ability to either draw a replacement Tides of Battle card or receive +1 combat strength?*
>
> A: If you are playing with Tides of Battle cards,
>   there are two opportunities for a player to use his
>   Valyrian Steel Blade:
>
> **1) "Choose and Reveal House card" step:** After each side draws a Tides of Battle card, but before they are revealed, he may decide to use the blade to draw a replacement Tides of Battle card.
>
> **2) "Use Valyrian Steel Blade" step:** If he has not used it yet this round, he may now decide to use the blade to add +1 to his combat strength.

The ambiguity is in the last sentence:

> *[...] he may **now** decide to use the blade [...]*

Well, when is *now*? I understand that first you will have to decide whether or not you want to use the Blade to draw a replacement Tides of Battle card. You will decide this after you look at your drawn card, before it is revealed. OK so far. Let's say I choose not to use it. OK so I still can use the sword to get +1 combat point. **But when, exactly?? Before or after I see my opponent's Tides of Battle card?**

Comment: I think the real question is less about when to play the VSB, and more about when to reveal the ToB cards.

Comment: To downvoter: why? How can I improve this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Now" means during the step being discussed by that explanation: the *Valyrian Steel Blade* step.

The *Valyrian Steel Blade* step is the fourth out of six parts in combat, as listed in the rules.

It occurs **after** the *Choose and Reveal House Cards* step, which is third out of six.

The rulebook and the FAQ/errata both imply that the Blade happens after the TOB cards. Either the TOB is "part of" the House Cards step, or the Blade follows the choice and revelation of TOB cards.

Nevertheless, you will have seen your opponent's Tide of Battle card (and thus know the pending result of combat) before you decide whether to use the Blade.

Comment: By *opponent's card* you mean the House card or the Tides of Battle card? I already know that I will have seen my opponent's House card. I think you mean the ToB card, but just wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: The rulebook and the FAQ/errata both imply that the Blade happens after the TOB cards. Either the TOB is "part of" the *House Cards* step, or the Blade follows the choice and revelation of TOB cards.

Comment: I see, thanks! I suggested an edit to further clarify that in the answer.